# Is there a difference between あまり食べ過ぎる and 食べ過ぎる?

Tags: grammar

あまり and 過ぎる both indicate an excess of something, so saying あまり食べ過ぎる seems redundant and the equivalent of "eat too too much." However, a sentence like this occurs [quite often](http://classic.jisho.org/sentences?jap=amari%20sugi&eng=). Is there actually any difference in meaning compared to simply saying 食べ過ぎる or あまり食べる?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using similar words twice, it says the excess is even more excessive. For example,

> 少しだけなら食べ過ぎても大丈夫だけど、あまり食べ過ぎるとお腹が痛くなるよ。

If you just eat a little too much, that's OK, but if you eat really too much, you'll get a stomachache.